# Issue with jquery ui in element having resizable and draggable both

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

I have applied jquery ui resizable and draggable on same element. I have provided boundaries with containtment element for both operation. but when resize exceed to containtment element boundary, it starts drag operation with resizable handle. how to prevent this?

```
$("#ui_div").resizable({
    handles: 'n,e,s,w',
    containment: $("#img1"),
    start: function (e, ui) {
    },
    stop: function (e, ui) {
    }
});

$("#ui_div").draggable({
    appendTo: 'body',
    containment: $("#img1"),
    start: function (e, ui) {
    },
    stop: function (e, ui) {
    }
});
```

This is my sample code. problem is that when I resize and It reaches containment element boundary i.e '$("#img1")' then top resize handler start to drag element outside boundary of containment element. this happening only for top and left resizing.

Comment: Please put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in the question itself.

Comment: I have updated my question.